# Disable some parts of layout in the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, popup

I'm building my first rails app just right now and now I have a problem.
I have an application layout which includes an header and a footer (and of course the content). Now I have a popup in one view (I use [Facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox)) which works well, except I don't want to show the footer in the page loaded via ajax.

I don't know how I can do that ... is there a way how I could add something like this option to the URL?
I would already be very happy if you could just give me an idea how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to change layout of a page that is shown inside the popup? If so, check please `:layout` options of the `render` method. You can use another layout, or no layout at all.

You can do it in your controller. Either create new action for "footerless" page (don't forget to modify routes.rb)

```
def show_footerless (user/1/show_footerless)
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  render "show", :layout => "footerless" # or :layout => nil
end
```

Or pass extra param to standard action (/user/1?footerless=1)

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if params[:footerless]==1
    render "show", :layout => "footerless" # or :layout => nil
  else
    render "show"
  end
end
```

Comment: This sounds good, but is it also possible to set the layout in the URL somehow? (I'm loading the other page via AJAX)

Answer (score 0):

You can do, when opening the popup

```
@popup_displayed = true
```

Then in the layout

```
<%= render 'layouts/footer' unless @popup_displayed %>
```

Comment: This could work, but I don't know how I could set the `@popup_displayed` from the client side. Can I add the parameter to **all** routes or something like that so that this would be an option in the URL?